# Downloading Text Files from a list of URLs

Tags: python

I have a list of URLs in which there is a text file to download and save.

I have successfully downloaded and saved the first file using the code below.

I have a dataframe that has the download url in one column and the destination pathway in another.

```
request.urlretrieve(df['download_url'].iloc[0],df['destination_folder']
```

Is there a way to use a loop or something to run through ALL of the urls and download the files into the associated destination folder?

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
for url in df['download_url']:
    request.urlretrieve(df['download_url'], df['destination_folder'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `iterrows` function:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    request.urlretrieve(row['download_url'],row['destination_folder'])
```

Answer (score 2):

To build on the answer above, the reason it doesn't work is because `df['destination_folder'] and df['download_url']` is a pandas series - i.e. you are not extracting one file name but what is basically a list of file names. Using `row['destination_folder']` as mentioned above accessed the column value for `destination_folder` at a specific row.

Comment: Thank you, @dvr . I'm still learning and this made a lot of sense and I appreciate you taking the time to share your knowledge.

Comment: No worries. I figured you may want to know why it happened rather than just the fix with no explanation.